# Issue while store email store with % sign

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

Hi I have store data from frontend to MySQL DB and retrieving them to frontend but after I update the email and save, it saves like **abs%gmail.com instead abs@gmail.com.** When I saving them for the first time no issues occur, I have looked solutions from stack overflow, git and ext. but any of those did not work.

**Any solution will be generally appreciating.**

Comment: Whatever your programming language is (Java is not JavaScript) it'll surely have prepared statements. Just use that instead of your homebrew escaping system.

Answer (score 0):

it's encoded

simply decode it in your flow

`decodeURIComponent('abs%40gmail.com')` // result: "abs@gmail.com"

`encodeURIComponent('abs@gmail.com')` // result: "abs%40gmail.com"